# How to Set Tempo/BitRate for MP3 files in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mp3, core-audio, bitrate

I am trying to change the tempo of the MP3 file to b saved in iPhone. I know it is streaming type audio, but is there a way to permanently reflect such a change?
I am able to [musicPlayer setRate:float_value] for playing the audio with the changed bit rate, is it possible to also store it somehow?

Or is it possible to internally record the same file into another file while playing it with the changed bit-rate.
Please help me with this issue.
Thank you in advance!